# Using C# to control media en application volumes

Tags: c#, audio, serial-port, media, mixer

I'm trying to build my own mixer panel and got the hardware and software communication side working now all i need is to control the media on my computer using this. How do i control the media en stuff like volume on a window's computer the program i made is written en C# and communicates via serial to my mixer board based on Arduino. I searched around but i can't find a lot about controlling media using C# or volume control there seems to be nothing in the standard C# libraries about this.

I want it to be able to skip songs or go back and do the standard media control like this. I also got different sliders for volume and want to control the volume of different applications using this.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AudioSwitcher.AudioApi.CoreAudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For controlling media you can use virtual keyboard inputs by hooking into the user32 DLL to virtual press the media control keys. This way you can do things like mute and skip to next track, but the Volume Control is limited to just controlling the main device volume just like a normal keyboard. Below is a simple code snipped of how to do this.

```
public class VirtualMediaController
{
    internal enum VirtualKeyCodes
        : uint
    {
        VOLUME_MUTE = 0xAD,
        VOLUME_DOWN = 0xAE,
        VOLUME_UP = 0xAF,
        NEXT_TRACK = 0xB0,
        PREVIOUS_TRACK = 0xB1,
        STOP = 0xB2,
        PLAY_PAUSE = 0xB3,
        LAUNCH_MEDIA = 0xB5,
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    internal static extern void keybd_event(uint bVk, uint bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);

    internal static void SendKey(VirtualKeyCodes virtualKeyCode)
    {
        keybd_event((uint)virtualKeyCode, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static void Mute()
    {
        SendKey(VirtualKeyCodes.VOLUME_MUTE);
    }

    public static void VolumeDown()
    {
        SendKey(VirtualKeyCodes.VOLUME_DOWN);
    }

    public static void VolumeUp()
    {
        SendKey(VirtualKeyCodes.VOLUME_UP);
    }

    public static void NextTrack()
    {
        SendKey(VirtualKeyCodes.NEXT_TRACK);
    }

    public static void PreviousTrack()
    {
        SendKey(VirtualKeyCodes.PREVIOUS_TRACK);
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        SendKey(VirtualKeyCodes.STOP);
    }

    public static void PlayPause()
    {
        SendKey(VirtualKeyCodes.PLAY_PAUSE);
    }

    public static void LaunchMedia()
    {
        SendKey(VirtualKeyCodes.LAUNCH_MEDIA);
    }
}
```

For more accurate Volume Control you will have to use a library or build one that will hook into the windows mixer API. CoreAudio [Github](https://github.com/morphx666/CoreAudio) is an example of such a library and can be used as a jumping of point. It can be used to control audio output devices and gives you more fin grain control over the audio then just using a visual keyboard for the media keys (volume up, volume down and mute). This way you can also get information like current volume and mute status. But this type of library wont give you the play/pause and stop functionality so a combination of both options is best.